# How to get the comments ids when emptying comments trash?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a hook when "empty trash" comments. I will need all the `comment_id` and `post_id` on this hook.

Conceptually, I would need a hook something to look like this

```
add_action('comment_empty_trash', 'myFunction');
function myFunction($array_comment_ids) {

  $array_comment_ids = [
    126 => // post id 
      [122, 648, 52], // comment ids
    127 => // post id 
      [127, 698, 72], // comment ids
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "empty_trash" hook. It doesn't exist.

But you can use the `delete_comment` action hook.

The "problem" is that you wont have an array of comment ids, but you'll have to act on each comment individually.

E.g.:

```
add_action( 'deleted_comment', function( $comment_id ) {
   do_your_thing_with_the_comment( $comment_id );
} );

function do_your_thing_with_the_comment( $comment_id ) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: It does not work on empty trash. Have any other solution?

Comment: Just tested it. It does work on empty trash. In the above example, it will call `do_your_thing_with_the_coment($comment_id)` for each comment in the trash being perma-deleted. There must be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @MDAbubakar Post what you are trying.

Comment: I have a list of omment id for every post. If comment deleted I want to remove this is from this list

Comment: It does, I've tested it. When you click on "Empty Trash", it fires once per comment deleted.